# Usage of "checkout" as a verb

Tags: grammaticality

What is the correct way to say?

> - A user can enter their address when checking out.
> - A user can enter their address when going through checkout.

Comment: Neither is correct. It should be "A user can enter *his/her* address..."

Comment: @Daniel That's another debate altogether! Personally I have no problem using "their" there.

Answer (score 4):

[*Checkout* is **not** a verb.](http://notaverb.com/checkout)

> Despite what many people --mostly in the computer field-- think, "checkout" is not a verb.  … this has nothing to do with verbification, or "verbing."  … the problem … is the manner in which that happens …

Dictionaries generally do not define *checkout* as a verb. Use it as a noun, or use separate words -- an idiomatic verb phrase -- *check out* for a verb.

> A user can enter their address when **checking out**. -- verb phrase -- correct.
>   A user can enter their address when going through **checkout**. -- noun -- correct!

also,

> A user can enter their address **at checkout**.  (at the time of/ point of checkout)